# How to properly log in a user from Owin Middleware

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm making my own system to authenticate jwt tokens in certain scenarios.

When I have properly validated the token, I have

```
var userIdentity = await user.CreateIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);
owinContext.Authentication.User = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
owinContext.Authentication.SignIn(userIdentity);
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = owinContext.Authentication.User;
await next()
```

but that doesn't seem to fix authentication which still fails at - I believe - the Asp.Net Mvc level. Because I know it uses `HttpContext` I try adding this before calling `next()`

```
HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(userIdentity, new string[0]);
```

This gets me further along but I still seem to be getting an an authorization error it would seem (by searching source for the message that I get and [where its used](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L156)) to be coming from the Web Api `[Authorize]` attribute.

I'm hitting a wall as far as tracing through the .net source code. The only way I should be getting this message is if [IsAuthorized](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L85) returns false. But there are no roles nor users specified (it's just plain `[Authorize]`) and before heading off to the `next()` I can stop the debugger and check that yes there is a user identity, and yes it `IsAuthorized`.

I've overridden the `AuthorizeAttribute` so as to place breakpoints and can see that by the time it is called however, my `actionContext` is associated with a completely different identity with `IsAuthorized == false`. Which in turn makes me wonder if I'm signing in the user identity wrong

So... *am* I doing this correctly? What should I be doing?

Answer (score 3):

I have never undertstood why but in my case, i have need to valid the ticket after signing in:

```
var userIdentity = await user.CreateIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);
ctx.Authentication.SignIn(userIdentity);
AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(userIdentity, null);
ctx.Validated(ticket);
```

**Edit**

I'm not really in the same context. In my case, I have a custom authentication provider inheriting of `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider` :

```
public class CustomBearerAuthenticationProvider:OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    public CustomBearerAuthenticationProvider() : base()
    {
        this.OnValidateIdentity = (context) => Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var identity = this.CreateApplicationIdentity(user);
            context.OwinContext.Authentication.SignIn(identity);
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, null);
            context.Validated(ticket);
        });
    }
}
```

`context` is of type : `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthValidateIdentityContext`

Comment: Where does `Validated` come from? I don't see that on `IOwinContext` and no extension method

Comment: My context is Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthValidateIdentityContext. I updatetd my answer

Comment: why `Task.Run`??

Comment: Can you show how you wire in your `CustomBearerAuthenticationProvider`? Also I'm confused why you chose `OnValidateIdentity` versus the other methods, it seems an odd choice to replace the identity using a validation method.